# mysql.sock not found, where can i find it?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

On a CentOS 7 machine, I am getting the following error when I try to log into mysql from the terminal:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I then tried `cd /var/lib/mysql` and `ls -al`, but the resulting list of files did not contain `mysql.sock`.  **So where can I find `mysql.sock` and how can I resolve this error?**

Here are a number of things I have tried already:

1.) When I saw that `systemctl status mysqld` showed that mysql was stopped, I also tried `systemctl start mysqld` but the terminal just gave an unresponsive cursor without a new prompt, as if it were held up waiting for something, but it remained in that limbo state indefinitely.

2.) So I opened another terminal window and ran `systemctl status mysqld`, only to see that mysqld was again started.  But the error persists.

3.) I tried `find / -name "mysql.sock"` but the response was `find: ‘/run/username/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied`.

4.) Then I read [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530215/mysql-problem-no-mysql-sock) and tried `mysqladmin | grep d.sock` but there were no results.

5.) I even resorted to `yum remove mysql` followed by `yum install mysql`, but then `mysql -u root` still gives the same original error at top of this posting.

6.) And then I read [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748478/cannot-find-mysql-sock), but `mysqladmin variables` gives the same error that it cannot connect because the `mysql.sock` cannot be found.

7.) And I tried `ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock` but the same error persisted even though a link to mysql became visible when I tried `cd /var/lib/mysql/` and `ls -al`

8.) Since the problem may have to do with the fact that `systemctl start mysqld` gets hung up, I read [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310782/mysql-daemon-failed-to-start-centos-6) and tried `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` and `systemctl start mysqld` but the result is `Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

9.) I then read [this posting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48777/mysql-sock-missing), which caused me to run `mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1`. The result printed the locations where `mysql` looks for `my.cnf`.  I thus checked every location, and there was no `my.cnf` file to be found. But I did find a `mysql.cnf.rpmsave`, so I tried `mv mysql.cnf mysql.cnf.rmpsave`.  This caused there to be a `my.cnf` in the expected directory, but `systemctl status mysqld` says that `mysqld` is not found.  I tried `yum install mysql` again, but it told me that `mysql` is already installed.  **So I suspect that the newly renamed `my.cnf` is corrupted.  If so, how can I fix it?**  [Here is the link](https://jumpshare.com/v/xImomZMASgLWPUZ4Ic70?b=rr8My67FzHTNqagmLbTg) to a copy of the newly renamed `my.cnf` on a file sharing site.

Comment: Man did you fix this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realise this is an old post, but came across this myself just now and found it very hard to find the proper solution.  I solved it by doing the following:

1. Install `zlib`:

   ```
   32-Bit Debian/Ubuntu: apt-get install zlib1g
   64-Bit Debian/Ubuntu: apt-get install lib32z1
   32/64-Bit Fedora: yum install zlib.i686
   32/64-Bit Mandriva: urpmi zlib1
   32-Bit SUSE: zypper install libz1
   64-Bit SUSE: zypper install libz1-32bit
   ```
2. Connect to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` if that option is available to you.  With MySQL connecting via `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` use different methods (TCP for the former, Sock for the latter)
3. Make sure your firewall isn't blocking ports internally, perhaps consider disabling it **temporarily** to make sure this isn't the case.

Comment: Thank you and+1 for taking the time to add insight into this old question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Detailed example](https://kb.hivelocity.net/what-to-do-if-mysql-sock-file-is-missing/) on how you can fix this issue. If you closely follow all of these steps then you should have it fixed in not time.

Comment: The link you sent did not work.  `Step 2` showed that there was NOT `mysql.sock` in either folder.  And `/usr/bin/mysql_install_db` in `step 6` threw an error.  Anyone can google a link to a tutorial like the one in your answer.  The number of attempts listed in my original post above shows I have already done a lot of web research on this.  I was hoping someone would actually look at this instead of just doing a quick google search that I have already done before posting.